# Using regression to both estimate and attribute a single value to a subset of established categories

Tags: regression, categorical-data, stata, finite-mixture-model

I am using Stata 15.1

I have a dataset with some 12,000 observations with a continuous dependent variable and 4 continuous independent variables. Each observation is also prior assigned to one of about 100 categories. Each category can belong to one of two cases, not known ex ante. In the first case the category represents a zero value in the regression. In the second case the category represents an unknown single value constant across the data set (for those observations with categories assigned to this second case).

I wish to combine the regression of the continuous data with an estimate of both which categories belong to which case, and what the single value is that is then common to the second case.

Comment: This looks like a [blind source separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=blind%20source%20separation) problem.  It is worth contemplating a simpler version in which the only explanatory variable is the intercept: this makes it obvious you are trying to fit a two-component [mixture model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mixture+model).

Comment: OK - So one way I can do this is to regress the continuous variables first and then look to allocate to the two cases. Can one solve this allocation problem in Stata?

Comment: I wonder about the mechanism or model for establishing the categories: the concern is whether they could be associated with any of the variables.  Could you say more about that?  And are we trying to estimate two intercepts or 100 separate ones?  Your language is ambiguous.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. Two intercepts. 100 intercepts and I could simply use regress with i.category. Yes, the categories are associated with the continuous variables, hence wishing to do the estimation in one stage. As I suggested below,  could regress the continuous variables first, and then assign the categories to cases based on the residual error terms. Sadly this is not an unbiased procedure. And if I then do this and then estimate the single value having fixed the case to category, with the continuous vars then again the significance tests with be biased.

Comment: Right: the bias is the reason why the current answer will almost certainly fail -- if it manages to obtain any results at all.  Significance tests don't seem to have a place here, though: you want to *classify* observations.  What hypothesis would you be testing?

Comment: Exactly! The hypothesis is that the attribution of category to case and the value of the non-zero case would not have occurred as the result of a random process. Clearly, a random data set would exhibit the opportunity for classification. One idea comes to mind, and that is the tests for there being underlying two (or more) overlapping normal distributions driving the value of the residual terms. What do you think?

Comment: Unfortunately, "not have occurred as the result of a random process" is not testable with these data.  (It doesn't mean anything, actually.)  I suppose you could test whether the categorization appears to be *independent* of any of the variables you have (or even of other variables that are not used in the regression).  What is especially interesting about such a formulation is it does not logically imply you need an unbiased classifier, perhaps opening the problem up to more or better solutions than otherwise might be proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, which I believe is likely valid. Note: You can likely  best fine tune the proposed process (for example, starting subsample size selection,...) by constructing a test population, which conforms to the assumptions of the regression model and for which, you known, as you are generating the data, all the true underlying values.

First, select a random subset of the population for data exploration. Guess (for example, assume all equal values) the starting values for "unknown single value constant across the data set" and iteratively apply the regression to arrive at improved estimates based on values from the prior run.

For the rest of the data set, apply regression analysis, where you have now fixed the "unknown single value constant across the data set" at the values determined in the subset analysis.

As to whether this approach is effective and degree of accuracy may be determined per the simulation exercise. Note, violation of regression assumptions in your real data set, like for example, non-normal errors, should be addressed (consider a transformations analysis) so that you do not overly state the accuracy of your final estimates.

Note: Some may suggest to directly employ a more complex minimization model, however, my experience is that these are not always better as testing on your simulation model database may confirm.

Comment: Could you explain how "iteratively apply the regression to arrive at improved estimates" would work?  It seems like you are just asking the reader to solve the problem with a smaller dataset--which would make it harder--without making any real advances on how to go about doing it.  I think I must be missing some key step.

Comment: Point 1. L-S assumes the independent variable is precisely known. Clearly violated here, so we are 'exploring' a subset for suggested values. Point 2:  Whatever estimate is provided is assumed fixed for the regression estimation Stage 2. I think starting with all values of the classes equal and look at regression fit measures to adjust, in the right direction, among the  classes. To the extent, you have other information, incorporate here. Note, I recommended a simulation data set for best practice determination, and expected improvement.

Comment: Clearly my point is determine if you can (using my rough guide) find a path, which is simulation verified, but still not exactly a guarantee. If someone has another more precisely detailed solution, employ and simulation verify as to actual performance and compare results.

Comment: I had thought to use optimisation to solve this mixed integer problem. But by doing so I loose any chance of establishing the significance of the coefficients. I am not sure how one could construct a test population for which one "knows" which class each classification belongs to - given that that is exactly the problem I am trying to solve. I suppose I could use some sort of search or clustering algorithm on the categories using the residuals of the classical regression model (excluding the categories) for a test set, and then apply to the population as a whole??

Comment: Just a suggested idea, consider not working  with 100 categories but a factor reduction of said categories. If categories are items, the factors may intuitively mean luxury goods, staples,...or unclear. The problem is reduced and one may understand the factor as a concept and some knowledge that relates, at least, to median pricing, for example.

Comment: Yes I can do this. But then I loose the value of any tests of significance. In fact I could then treat this as a sequential match process problem (or a simple clustering problem) and acknowledge that the stats are misleading.